# NHibernate mysql connection not closed?

Tags: mysql, nhibernate

I am using NHibernate with mySQL 5 and I am a bit unsure whether NHibernate really closes the connection to mySQL.

This is the code I am using in order to save a Player entity to the database:

```
        using (ISession session = SessionFactory.OpenSession())
        {
            using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
            {
                session.Save(player);
                transaction.Commit();
            }
        }
```

After running this piece of code, I select the current connection count from the mySQL server using

```
show status like 'Conn%' ;
```

and the value is increased every time by 1!

So, inserting the player 10 times (=starting the program 10 times) increases the connection count by 10. But the session.IsClosed property of the NHibernate Session is false.

Do I have to do anything else in order to release the NHibernate resources and close the connection? Are the connections pooled / timed out?

It would be great if anyone could give me a hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the Connection is being closed. The dispose method on the ISession does just that. So it's unlikely it remains open when exiting the using block.

Also , from what I know the connection is usually opened only when writing/reading to the database . The session may be open, but that doesn't mean the connection is also open.

That, plus the fact that in the [mysql documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Connections), it says that the keyword **Connections** means :

> **The number of connection attempts (successful or not) to the MySQL server.**

and doesn't say anything about the current state of the connection (open or not), makes me believe that the connection is closed.

PS: you should be using **Threads_connected** to see open connections.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in the MySQL.Data dll in certain versions that was causing this same problem for me. Make sure you update your Connector/NET to the most recent. This solved the problem for me.